# How to find Windows Universal app windows from C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to write my own program that lets me select one Window of ALL open windows and set the state of this window to TOP, so that this selected window will always show on top!

The problem... since Windows 8 there are APPs and actually the process comes up in the process explorer but my selection of my tool doesn't list it. (Its like there is no app)

My source looks like:

```
private void refreshWindowList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    windowList.Items.Clear();

    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses().Where(pp => pp.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero && pp.ProcessName != "explorer"))
    {
        windowList.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
    }
}
```

This function is called when I open my combobox and actually refresh the Items every time when I view the list.

I find normal programs, but is there a way to find Win 8/10 apps ?

**EDIT to clarify**: Normal processes like **notepad** can be found. But Windows Universal apps like e.g. **netflix** can't. At least I don't know how to find them.

Comment: Can you clarify: is the problem that you can't find Windows Universal apps? Or you don't know what to do once you've found them? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: i cant find them. Of course I know what to do with them...

Comment: OK. I've edited your title and tags to reflect that the issue is specifically with UWP apps.

Comment: Maybe you can't find them because they don't have a main window handle?

Comment: There must be something. I can see them in the TaskExplorer so I guess there must be some way to grab it. Or am I so wrong with my guesses ?

Comment: Did you try removing the condition "pp.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero"?

Comment: Yes, this Actually list me all what you can see in the details tab. Whats actually nice... but the application is not listet there ^^ devils circle :D

Comment: Assuming yms is correct, as I think he is, try using the winapi  to get all top level Windows.  Maybe  [by enumerating all top level Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thought I may can get around this :) obviously I wont :(

Comment: the powershell command get-appxpackage gives you all the store-apps installed on the system, maybe you can match some of the values there that with one of process properties

Comment: It is there, you just don't recognize it.  The Netflix app was written in Javascript, a language does not support creating executable files.  It runs inside a host, like it does inside a browser, the host process name is WWAHost.exe

Comment: So if I get you right, all apps are loaded in this WWAHost.exe? I truly saw this process but as you guessed right, I didn't recognized that this could be the window.

Comment: @Dwza not all of them. Just those written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some applications, e.g. Netflix, are written using HTML and JavaScript. These apps are hosted by [WWAHost](http://www.groovypost.com/tips/wwahost-exe-windows-process-safe-running-or-virus/):

> [...] Microsoft explains WWAHost as “an Internet Explorer-based rendering platform.”

You can check if this is the case for an app by right clicking it in the Task Manager and choosing *Go to details*:

> [image: task manager processes]
>
> [image: task manager details]

To find out which app is being hosted, you can use [`MainWindowTitle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName); // WWAHost
Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowTitle); // Netflix
```

Comment: Thank you for this good hint. Now I am able to perform my actions like I expact to do.